# In a dual-monitor setup does HDMI always become display #1?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, windows-8

I have a computer display plugged into a DVI port, and TV plugged into the HDMI port. Whenever I turn the TV on it becomes monitor #1.

This is more of an annoyance than a problem, as I can make my computer display the "main display".

The annoyance is that it makes the Windows UI not make sense.

[image: Second Screen]
Here selecting **PC screen only** turns of my computer display, and selecting **Second screen only** turns of my TV.

I have tried [editing the registry](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=657768), and the [suggestions here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/f9e088f5-5449-4ae6-97a3-92a972d3e1c6), but none of them work. As soon as I plug in my TV, it becomes monitor #1.

Based on what I've heard from other people with the same problem, it seems like HDMI will always take over as #1. Is that so?

Is there any way to correct it?

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/232968/how-to-assign-monitor-numbers-in-windows-7

Comment: @ronalchn I've read that UltraMon doesn't actually change the numbers. Plus, not exactly a $40 problem.

Comment: I am not advocating ultramon, I just linked to it because it appears there is no solution

Comment: I have the same problem and it is a PROBLEM because after sleep the desktop is shown only on the Display 1 (that is, TV).

Comment: @Anixx What I wound up doing is using a DVI to HDMI cable which I run to the TV, and using DisplayPort with the monitor. Things work out this way... =/

Answer (score 2):

Same issue for me. Seems that TV through HDMI always wants to be #1 display.
Although I don’t have any troubles with bootup or something else.. All perfectly fine except for Win+P menu. It completely mess around.
So I decide to cheat the system by editing resources.

I have English Win7 SP1 64bit (build7601) 96dpi. With two monitors connected: DVI for PC and TV through HDMI
If you have same setup you can repeat my way relatively safe.
But you MUST to know how to take ownership or boot from LiveCD. If not please don't do it. you can end up with unbootable PC (worst case)

Here is the [files](http://www.fileswap.com/dl/2RK7y857Fd/), just replace originals (you must to know how to.. if not, don't do it.) And don't forget to backup originals. I also replaced icons to win8 style.

This solution only for logical and good looking Win+P, and don't have any relationship to displays identification. (so it's even more mess from the system point of view)
I'm sorry for win7 answer to win8 thread. But this thread is very high at google search. Maybe some one find my solution helpful, I'm spent more then a hour to change resources and write this guide.

Edit: Now I have got some reputation and can attach an image

[image]

Comment: If the setting is to display the desktop only on one monitor, then after sleep the desktop is displayed only on monitor #1 (even if the setting was to display it on monitor #2). That is the desktop is only on the TV. Since the TV is in another room, I have to make a hard reboot every time after sleep. This is regardless what monitor is "main".

Answer (score 0):

No, you can change which display is your main display. To do this go to

> Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\Screen Resolution

either by right clicking on the desktop and selecting `Screen Resolution` or by hitting <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> and searching for it.

You will get this screen. Click on the appropriate monitor and check `Make this my main display`

[image]

Comment: This is what I've done, but it doesn't fix the issues I've described.

Comment: "This is more of an annoyance than a problem, as I can make my computer display the 'main display'."

Comment: Strange, I have 2 monitors through DVI and mini-displayport and one of them is set as the main monitor. When I turn on the TV I go to these settings and click Detect and it switches to my main monitor and the TV.

Comment: Sorry, I skimmed your question.

Comment: No prob... It's my suspicion that it has to do with HDMI. For example, I've read that people with other combinations of ports can just physically swap the cables to change the numbers.

Comment: Sounds like a Windows bug to me.

Comment: If the setting is to display the desktop only on one monitor, then after sleep the desktop is displayed only on monitor #1 (even if the setting was to display it on monitor #2). That is the desktop is only on the TV. Since the TV is in another room, I have to make a hard reboot every time after sleep. This is regardless what monitor is "main".